# ADD two selects together for a column then get sum totals for all selects

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, aggregate-functions

after 'SLG'
I'm trying to get an OPS column. In order to get it I need to add the OBS AND SLG together. I'm struggling to combine them together. Also, I'm trying to sum up the totals for all the selects used.

```
select nameFirst+' '+nameLast as 'NAME' ,G GP, AB,R,H,S,B2 as '2B',B3 as '3B',HR,RBI,

((S)+(b2*2)+(b3*3)+(hr*4)) as TB,

BB,SO,SB, H*1.0/(Case when AB=0 then 1 else AB end) as 'AVG',

((H+BB+HBP*1.0)/(Case when (AB+BB +HBP+SF)=0 then 1 else (AB+BB +HBP+S) end )) as 'OBS', 

((S)+(b2*2)+(b3*3)+(hr*4)*1.0)/(Case when AB=0 then 1 else AB end) as 'SLG'
  
from vwPlayersBatting
where teamID = 'hou' and yearID ='2005'  
order by AB DESC;
```

Comment: Reading and following this will increase your chances to get an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that the problem is that you are trying to do something like `(OBS + SLG) AS OPS` in your `SELECT` statement. You haven't shown what you tried so I am not sure, but I see my students often make this mistake.

In SQL, you cannot reference an alias in the `SELECT` list, so you have to use the full expression. You want `OBS + SLG`, so in this expression you will have to replace `OBS` with its definition, and you will have to replace `SLG` with its definition.

For your example, I suspect what you need is something like this:

```sql
SELECT nameFirst+' '+nameLast AS 'NAME',
       G,
       GP,
       AB,
       R,
       H,
       S,
       B2 AS '2B',
       B3 AS '3B',
       HR,
       RBI,
       ((S)+(b2*2)+(b3*3)+(hr*4)) AS TB,
       BB,
       SO,
       SB,
       H*1.0/(CASE
                  WHEN AB=0 THEN 1
                  ELSE AB
              END) AS 'AVG',
       ((H+BB+HBP*1.0)/(CASE
                            WHEN (AB+BB +HBP+SF)=0 THEN 1
                            ELSE (AB+BB +HBP+S)
                        END)) AS 'OBS',
       ((S)+(b2*2)+(b3*3)+(hr*4)*1.0)/(CASE
                                           WHEN AB=0 THEN 1
                                           ELSE AB
                                       END) AS 'SLG',
       ((H+BB+HBP*1.0)/(CASE
                            WHEN (AB+BB +HBP+SF)=0 THEN 1
                            ELSE (AB+BB +HBP+S)
                        END)) + ((S)+(b2*2)+(b3*3)+(hr*4)*1.0)/(CASE
                                                                    WHEN AB=0 THEN 1
                                                                    ELSE AB
                                                                END) AS 'OPS'
FROM vwPlayersBatting
WHERE teamID = 'hou'
  AND yearID ='2005'
ORDER BY AB DESC;
```